# Is there a feat or a class feature in 3.5e that is similar to Step Up (Combat) from Pathfinder?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, reach, melee-combat

I am looking for a feat that in some way resembles Step Up from Pathfinder:

> **Step Up (Combat)**
>
> You can close the distance when a foe tries to move
> away.
>
> *Prerequisite*: Base attack bonus +1.
>
> *Benefit*: Whenever an adjacent foe attempts to take a 5-foot step away
> from you, you may also make a 5-foot step as an immediate action so
> long as you end up adjacent to the foe that triggered this ability. If
> you take this step, you cannot take a 5-foot step during your next
> turn. If you take an action to move during your next turn, subtract 5
> feet from your total movement.

My goal is to **prevent a caster to take a 5-foot step** away from me while we are engaged in melee, in this way he/she is forced to cast defensively.

I understand that a weapon with reach could easily do the trick, but I can not consider this option.

So, is there any **Feat** or **Class Feature** that could help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A combination of the *thicket of blades* stance and the Evasive Reflexes feat, both from *Tome of Battle*, allows you to do this. *Thicket of blades* is available by dipping a level of crusader, or taking the Martial Study feat followed by the Martial Stance feat, all of which are also from *Tome of Battle*. It costs more, but it also does more, since *thicket of blades* allows 5-ft. steps to always provoke from you, and Evasive Reflexes allows you to 5-ft. step any time an attack of opportunity is provoked, and step in any direction.

The biggest problem is that *thicket of blades* is a 3rd-level stance, which means you have to be 9th level to get it with a dip or feat, or just be a 5th-level crusader.

Answer (score 3):

The Pursue feat from Eberron Campaign Setting, page 58, allows you to 5-foot-step into a square that an opponent you threaten takes a 5-foot-step out of, in exchange for 1 action point.

> PURSUE [GENERAL]
>
> You have the ability to follow in an opponent’s wake.
>
> Prerequisite: Combat Reflexes.
>
> Benefit: In combat, when an opponent in an adjacent square takes a single 5-foot step to a square that you do not threaten, you can spend 1 action point to move into the square the opponent just left. This movement occurs after the 5-foot step but before any other actions, and it does not provoke attacks of opportunity.

Comment: +1 for a valid answer to the question, but hoo boy, that is not a strong option. Action points are much too limited for this.

Comment: I had never looked into the Action Point variant rules... but yeah this would very rarely be worth a resource that does not replenish ever. Good find though. Might be necessary if a group doesn't play with Tome of Battle.